# How to send all network traffic from Docker container through a proxy?

Tags: docker, proxy

I want to send all network traffic from a Docker container through a proxy.  I *do not* want to proxy requests to Docker hub when building containers.

I've tried defining an environment variable HTTP_PROXY in my Dockerfile:

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://<myproxy address>.com:8010
```

...and I see:

```
starting http://<myproxy address>.com:8010
```

When I start the container.  However when I connect to the container and run curl:

```
docker exec -it <my container> /bin/bash
curl http://httpbin.org/ip
```

I see my IP, not the IP of the proxy indicating the proxy isn't working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lower case for `http_proxy`

```
ENV http_proxy http://<myproxy address>.com:8010
```

Comment: I think this only send traffic through the proxy if the underlying services respect "http_proxy".  But for my purposes it was enough, thanks

Comment: Correct, redirecting _all_ network traffic requires something other than a proxy.